# How is it possible to compare ASGI framework with ASGI server?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, uvicorn, asgi, starlette

How is it possible to compare ASGI framework with ASGI server? What the points of comparison? What the reason of comparison framework and server?

In this benchmark i see Starlette (ASGI framework) and Uvicorn (ASGI server),
actually Starlette works over the Uvicorn.

How it is possible to compare them?
Am i right - it's the same like compare warm with salty?

https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#hw=ph&test=fortune&l=zijzen-sf

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Yes, it doesn't make sense to compare the web framework with the server. The scopes are different.

That said... The application used to benchmark `uvicorn` is a pure ASGI application.

You can see the application used for TechEmpower [here](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/Python/uvicorn/app.py). With this setup, there's no overhead of the web framework itself.

The Starlette benchmark runs on `uvicorn` as well, and you can see the code [here](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/master/frameworks/Python/starlette).

Disclaimer: I'm maintainer of Uvicorn & Starlette. - It really doesn't matter for this question, it's just to give a bit of credibility.